# NoClassDefFoundError without a class name

Tags: java

I'm not quite sure if this is specific to Sun Java Systems Application Server but there are occasions where I run into a NoClassDefFoundError where the class in question, the one not found, is not mentioned in the error.

Does anyone know what conditions would lead to a NoClassDefFoundError being raised without specifying which class was not found?

Edit: Java 1.4

Comment: Hmm,.. I have definitely seen it before. Interested to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you using Java 5 ?

There is a bug about your problem and it is corrected for Java 6.

[Here is the reference](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4649144)